# Problema Update Banco "literal de string extenso demais"

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, codeigniter, sql-update

Estou com um problema na hora de fazer o `Update` de um conteúdo para o banco de dados, abaixo o código usado para o `Update`

```
public function atualizar_conteudo_manual() {
    $dadosmanual_update = array ("id_processo_manual"=>$this->id,
    "conteudo"=>$this->conteudo);
    $this->db->where('id_processo_manual', $dadosmanual_update['id_processo_manual']);
    $this->db->set('conteudo', $dadosmanual_update['conteudo']);
    $this->db->update('tb_processos_manuais',$dadosmanual_update);
}
```

Pois bem, eu consigo fazer o `Update` do conteúdo, porém quando ele é extenso demais ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Message: "oci_execute(): ORA-01704: literal de string extenso demais"

Gostaria de saber se é possível uma conversão para outro tipo de dado antes do `Update`, para este problema não ocorrer. De preferência a conversão para o tipo Blob.

Comment: invert o set com o where

Comment: ok invertido, mas a questão não é essa

Comment: Que eu me lembro isso já resolveria seu problema, não funcionou?

Comment: Você ta usando qual banco de dados?

Comment: Estou usando o Oracle Database

Comment: Tira o set para testar.

Comment: Tirei, o erro permanece com uma quantidade grande de dados, com pouco ele funciona mesmo sem o set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema do **Update** de Conteúdo extenso demais para o banco, resolvido com comandos OCI para comunicação com o banco Oracle, segue o código:

```html
public function atualizar_conteudo_manual(){
        $sql = "UPDATE tb_processos_manuais SET conteudo = ' ' , titulo = :titulo, chave_amigavel = :chave_amigavel WHERE id_processo_manual = :id RETURNING conteudo into :conteudo";
        $stmt = oci_parse($this->db->conn_id, $sql);
        $lob = oci_new_descriptor($this->db->conn_id, OCI_D_LOB); 
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':conteudo', $lob, -1, OCI_B_CLOB);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':titulo', $this->titulo,50);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':chave_amigavel', $this->chave_amigavel,50);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':id', $this->id,5);
        oci_execute($stmt, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
        $lob->save($this->conteudo);        
        oci_commit($this->db->conn_id);        
        oci_free_statement($stmt);
        $lob->free();
    }
```